# Unicity of modifications of vector bundle on a regular base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

I think that I have overheard the following statement, and would be grateful for either a reference or an explanation about why hearing must be slightly faulty and a clarification about what must actually have been said:

Let $X$ be a regular scheme, and let $D_1,\dots, D_n$ be a collection of irreducible divisors on $X$ with generic points $\eta_1,\dots, \eta_n$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Then for any collection of subspaces $S_i\subset\mathcal{F}|_{\eta_i}$ of the fibres of $\mathcal{F}$ over the $\eta_i$, there is a unique lower modification $\iota\colon\mathcal{F}_1\to\mathcal{F}$ such that $$\iota|_{\eta_i}(\mathcal{F}_1|_{\eta_i})=S_i\subset\mathcal{F}|_{\eta_i}.$$

Here by lower modification I think that I just mean a coherent subsheaf such that the inclusion is an isomorphism away from a union of divisors. I believe that the recipe for $\mathcal{F}_1$ is simply
$$
\mathcal{F}_1(U)=\{s\in\mathcal{F}(U)\mid s|_{\eta_i}\in S_i\}.
$$

I think that I must be misunderstanding something very basic, because it seems like
$$
\mathcal{O}(-2x)\to\mathcal{O}(-x)\to\mathcal{O}
$$
for $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $D=\{x\}$ some closed point gives a counter-example to the statement.